# Endomorphism - image and kernel question

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $f$ is an endomorphism of $V$, show that $f^2(v)=0, v\neq0,$ iff im$(f) \subset$ ker$(f)$.

My solution:

$$
v = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + \cdots + a_nv_n\\
f(v) = a_1f(v_1) + a_2f(v_2) + \cdots + a_nf(v_n)\\
f(f(v)) = f^2(v) = a_1f^2(v_1) + a_2f^2(v_2) + \cdots + a_nf^2(v_n) = 0\\
$$

But from the first relation of $v$, you get that $v\neq0$ so $a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n$ are different than 0 too, and because of that, to the last relation be true we'll need that $f^2(v)$ maps any $v$ to $\vec{0}$, hence im$(f) \subset$ ker$(f)$.

Am I correct?!

Thanks

Comment: Can you restate your concluding line?  It sounds like you're concluding that not all $a_i$'s are zero so $f^2(v)=0$ for any $v$ so im$(f) \subset $ ker$(f)$.  But $f^2(v)=0$ for any $v$ is one of your assumptions in this theorem so that shouldn't immediately lead to your conclusion (or else the proof would be trivial).  Also this is an iff proof, so you should prove the if and the only if parts separately.

Comment: reasoning not clear. mine is natural.

Comment: @Bye_World what i'm trying to get is that if $f^2(v) = 0$ and all $a_i$'s are different than $0$, so every $f^2(v)$ needs to map to $\vec{0}$ to make that statement, $f^2(v)=0$ true. what's wrong with that? please help me... Am i confused or wrong?!?!

Comment: "every $f^2(v)$ needs to map to $\vec 0$ to make that statement, $f^2(v)=0$, true".  So you're saying $f^2(v)=0\implies f^2(v)=0$?  Isn't that a tautology?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have Idea on what I'm talking about... I'm pissed off with this exercise... please help me

Comment: You don't need to assume finite-dimensional here, nor do you need to assume a choice of basis.

Comment: I don't need but I wanted too, to help with my "proof"...

Comment: @BrunoReis Look at Abdallah's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From left to right $(\implies)$.

Let $w$ be a non zero element of im$(f)$.

this means that

$\exists v\in V \backslash \{0\} : f(v)=w$

but $f(w)=f(f(v))=0$

so

$w \in $ Ker$(f)$.

conclusion

each element of imf$(f)$ is in Ker$(f)$.

From right to left

Assume im$(f) \subset$Ker$(f)$.

let $v$ be in $V \backslash \{0\}$

we want to show that $f(f(v))=0$.

$f(v) \in$ im$(f) \implies$

$f(v)\in$ Ker$(f) \implies$

$f(f(v))=0$.

Comment: Is my answer correct?!

Comment: @Bye_World ok i call it V.

Comment: why "but $f(w)=f(f(v))=0$"?!

Comment: it's because $f^2(v)$ is in the image of that transformation?!

Comment: by hypothesis$f^2(v)=0=f(f(v))$

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Just a minor criticism.  Your forward proof (the $\implies$ part) doesn't cover the null endomorphism (which is fine as it's easily done as a separate case).  Just pointing that out.

Comment: I can't agree with ur proof @AbdallahHammam I just doesn't understand it... what's that \V{0} thing?!

Comment: @BrunoReis That is the the vector space $V$, as a set, without the zero vector.

Comment: if $v=0$then  $ f(v)=0=f^2(v))$.

Comment: Ok so let's see.. you assume that $w$ is some nonzero element in your image... hence $f(v) = w$ for any $v \neq 0$.
Then you said $f(w) = f^2(v) = 0$ but why are you assuming that?! 
really, why?!?!

Comment: ooooh $f(w)$ is $f(f(v))$.... now I'm getting it...

Comment: look at your hypothesis.

Comment: I was pissed of before and couldn't get what you were doing... It's perfect now, thank you a lot!!!

Comment: @BrunoReis Ok friend .good night.